# Euclid algorithm - linear combination

Tags: algorithms, divisibility

I've been taught that Euclids algorithm for $(a,b), a > b $ can be used to find $x,y$ such that $ax + by = d$, where $d$ is their GCD. However, the only method we have used to obtain this is by making a table of all the quotients and then following the set of recursions:

$x_i=x_{i-2} - q_ix_{i-1},
y_i=y_{i-2} - q_iy_{i-1}$

until we reach the last quotient.

My question is, is there a faster way to find $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do it by hand is in analogy to Gaussian elimination or triangularization, except that, since the coefficient ring is not a field, one has to use the division / Euclidean algorithm to iteratively descrease the coefficients till zero. In order to compute both $\rm\,gcd(a,b)\,$ *and* its Bezout linear representation $\rm\,j\,a+k\,b,\,$ we keep track of such linear representations for each remainder in the Euclidean algorithm, starting with the trivial representation of the gcd arguments, e.g. $\rm\: a = 1\cdot a + 0\cdot b.\:$ In matrix terms, this is achieved by augmenting (appending) an identity matrix that accumulates the effect of the elementary row operations. Below is an example from one of my old posts. It computes the Bezout representation for $\rm\:gcd(80,62) = 2\ $ viz. $\ 7\cdot 80\: -\:  9\cdot 62\ =\ 2\:.\:$

```
For example, to solve  m x + n y = gcd(m,n) one begins with
two rows  [m   1    0], [n   0    1], representing the two
equations  m = 1m + 0n,  n = 0m + 1n. Then one executes
the Euclidean algorithm on the numbers in the first column,
doing the same operations in parallel on the other columns,

Here is an example:  d =  x(80) + y(62)  proceeds as:

                      in equation form   | in row form
                    ---------------------+------------
                    80 =   1(80) + 0(62) | 80   1   0
                    62 =   0(80) + 1(62) | 62   0   1
 row1 -   row2  ->  18 =   1(80) - 1(62) | 18   1  -1
 row2 - 3 row3  ->   8 =  -3(80) + 4(62) |  8  -3   4
 row3 - 2 row4  ->   2 =   7(80) - 9(62) |  2   7  -9
 row4 - 4 row5  ->   0 = -31(80) -40(62) |  0 -31  40

The row operations above are those resulting from applying
the Euclidean algorithm to the numbers in the first column,

        row1 row2 row3 row4 row5
namely:  80,  62,  18,   8,   2  = Euclidean remainder sequence
               |    |
for example   62-3(18) = 8, the 2nd step in Euclidean algorithm

becomes:   row2 -3 row3 = row4  when extended to all columns.
```

In effect we have row-reduced the first two rows to the last two.
    The matrix effecting the reduction is in the bottom right corner.
    It starts as $\,1,\,$ and is multiplied by each elementary row operation, 
    hence it accumulates the product of all the row operations, namely:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 7 & -9\\ -31 & 40\end{array}\right ]
   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 80 & 1 & 0\\ 62 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right ]
\ =\  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 7 & -9\\ 0 & -31 & 40\end{array}\right ]
$

```
Note row 1 is the particular  solution  2 =   7(80) -  9(62)
Note row 2 is the homogeneous solution  0 = -31(80) + 40(62),
so the general solution is any linear combination of the two:

          n row1 + m row2  ->  2n = (7n-31m) 80 + (40m-9n) 62
```

Below is a worked example free of verbiage, computing $\ \gcd(141,19),\ $ shown firstly  in the full equational form, and secondly in the more concise tabular form.
$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1)\quad \color{#C00}{141}\!\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, +\ 0&\cdot& 19 \\
(2)\quad\ \color{#C00}{19}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 0&\cdot& 141\, +\ 1&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(1)-7\,(2)}\, \rightarrow\, (3)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, -\ 7&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(2)-2\,(3)}\,\rightarrow\,(4)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3}\ &=&\, {-}2&\cdot& 141\, + 15&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(3)-3\,(4)}\,\rightarrow\,(5)\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 7&\cdot& 141\, -\color{}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{}{19} \end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$ 
 $$\rm\begin{eqnarray}                  &&(1)\quad \color{#C00}{141} &\ \ \  1 &\quad\ \  0 \\
                                       &&(2)\quad\ \color{#C00}{19} &\ \ \  0 &\quad\ \  1 \\
\color{#940}{(1)-7\,(2)}\,\rightarrow\,&&(3)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8} &\ \ \ 1 &\  -7\\
\color{#940}{(2)-2\,(3)}\,\rightarrow\,&&(4)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3} &    -2 &\ \ \ \, 15 \\
\color{#940}{(3)-3\,(4)}\,\rightarrow\,&&(5)\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1} &\ \ \  7 & \, \color{}{{-}52} \end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$ 
The same row/column reduction techniques tackle arbitrary
    systems of linear Diophantine equations. Such techniques
    generalize easily to similar coefficient rings possessing a
    Euclidean algorithm, e.g. polynomial rings $\,F[x]\,$ over a field, 
    Gaussian integers $\,\Bbb Z[i].\,$ There are many interesting
    closely related ideas, e.g. search on keywords: Hermite / Smith normal form, 
    invariant factors, lattice basis reduction, continued fractions,
    Farey fractions / mediants, Stern-Brocot tree / diatomic sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Euclidean algorithm "backwards" to get the general solution. Let's divide out the GCD to get a $1$ on the right hand side.
Example: $5x+13y=1$ Then $13=2*5+3$ then $5=1*3+2$ then $3=1*2+1$ backwards: $2*3-1*5=1$ then $3-(5-1*3)=1$ then $2(13-2*5)-1*5=1$ to get $2*13-5*5=1$ amd so we find a solution $x=-5,y=2$ introducing parameter $t$ to find a general set: $x=13t-5,y=-5t+2$ Watch how I took opposite signs of the t-coefficients!
I found using Euclid's algorithm backwards a very fast way to get a general set of solutions in parametric form